# Hoemomorphisms preserving closures of interiors of closed sets

Tags: general-topology

> If $D \subseteq X$ is a closed set that is homeomorphic to a closed set $E \subseteq Y$ with $\text{Int} (D)$ homeomorphic to $\text{Int}(E)$ and $\text{Cl}_Y(\text{Int}(E)) = E$ can we conclude that $\text{Cl}_X(\text{Int}(D)) = D$?

This is a question I came up with, when I was trying to work through a seperate problem. I'm guessing the answer to it is the proof for this is either really trivial (in which case it would just follow from the properties of hoemomorphisms) or there exists a counter example for it, but I'm stuck trying to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in D$ and let $V$ be a neighborhood of $x$ (in $D$); you want to prove that  $V$ contains some point $y\in\mathring D$. Let $f\colon D\longrightarrow E$ be a homeomorphism. Since $f$ is a homeomorphism, $f(V)$ is a neighborhood of $f(x)$ and therefore, since we are assuming that $E=\overline{\mathring E}$, there is a $z\in f(V)$ such that $z\in\mathring E$. Take $y=f^{-1}(z)$. Note that $f^{-1}\left(\mathring E\right)$ is an open subset of $D$ and that therefore $f^{-1}\left(\mathring E\right)\subset\mathring D$. In particular, $y\in\mathring D$. Since $y\in V$, we're done.

Comment: My edit was for a tiny typo in the 1st sentence :"...to  prove that $V$..." for "... to prove the $V$... "......+1

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I knew that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:D \to E$ be a homeomorphism. Let $d \in D$. Then $f(d)$ is the limit of  a net ${x_i}$ in Int(E). Let $y_i=f^{-1} (x_i)$. Then $\{{y_i}\}$ is a net in Int(D) converging to $d$.  Hence $D$ is contained in the closure of its interior.

Comment: Is there a proof that doesn't require the use of nets/filters? If so could you add it below the proof above.